# Bootstrap dropdown remove listener click outside

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, listener, event-listener

I'm using Bootstrap's dropdown menu and I need to remove the event listener which handles the "click outside". I mean when the user clicks outside the menu, no actions are made on the menu itself. I've tried to `$("body").off("bs.dropdown");` but it is not working. 
Example code: http://www.bootply.com/NSpuD4HI55
(try to click everywhere on the page)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('body').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
  return false;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work either, thanks for answering anyway.